# linq query to update multiple rows

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to update multiple rows using linq. My table structure is as below.

```
id  uploadID   Label            Value
1   100        docNumber        123
2   100        expiryDate       1/1/2017
```

My DAL function is as below.

```
 public int updatedocDetails(int upld_id, string docnumber, string expiryDate, string username)
{

}
```

In function i am recieving uploadId(for ex 100) and (docNumber for ex 456 and expiryDate for ex 2/2/2017)

So my resulting table should be

```
id  uploadID   Label            Value
1   100        docNumber        456 
2   100        expiryDate       2/2/2017
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this by using Linq? thank you in advance

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: yes  var docs = (from c in db.tr_upld_content where c.upld_docid == upld_id select c);
                foreach(var a in docs)
                {
                    a.upld_contentvalue = docnumber;
                }

Comment: this will update only one row but second row will not update and for second row i want to pass expirtydate not docunumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
List<Record> records = (from p in Context.Records
                        where .... // add where condition here
                        select p).ToList();

records[0].Value = 456;
records[1].Value = '2/2/2017';

Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: superb.. Worked fine